# Stop counting time in django

Tags: python, django, datetime, timezone

I've got a problem with take constant value from this function:

```
def get_time_left(self)
    now = timezone.now()
    time_left = self.deadline - now
    return time_left
```

self.deadline is value from model.

For example I want to take time_left from 15.00 2.09.2016, save it and use this value in another function, but when I try to do this, the value is always changing...

Comment: You'll need to explain in a bit more detail. Calling that function will always return the updated time_left; but if you save it in a variable the value of that variable won't change.

Comment: Could you provide the rest of the code and some further context? Where are you trying to use the result?

Comment: Shouldn't it always be changing? It is the "time left" before the deadline is reached. Each time you call `get_time_left()` it will be closer to (or even after) the deadline. Where and why do you want to save it?

Comment: Because I need to stop counting at 15.00 and return at 19.00 every day and I thought, that I save value from this hour, and at 19.00 I wil use it... I want to do this by crontab

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an easy workaround would be to have the value in the others function definition ? That way you are certain of what you send...

Yet, if you set the result of get_time_left() in a variable, it should not change...

More code would be helpfull indeed